Bounds on the problematic number of threads
Consider $n$ independent threads solving together a problem $P$. Thread-safety is here, roughly, a property of algorithms to solve the problem such that the concurrent execution of the problem does not give a wrong result or violate (e. g. time) constraints compared to the serial execution.
We say that the algorithm is of thread-safe-problem-type $k$ ("tspt-$k$") if at least $k > 2$ threads are needed to violate thread-safety (see the fruitfulness-assumptions below), e. g. by a thoughtful constructed interfering access to a variable. It seems to be common sense that nearly all thread-safety violation problems in concurrent algorithms / algorithm implementations can be reproduced using only a small number of threads ( = is of low tspt-$k$).
My question: Are there any known bounds regarding $k$? I am searching for results like e. g.:

"Thread-safety counterexamples can become arbitrarily complicated." For each $k$, there is a reasonable tspt-$k$ algorithm, ideally explicitely constructed.
"Nearly all thread-safe problems can be demonstrated with few threads". Assuming a reasonable distribution on some subset of all algorithms, there is a $k^\star$ such that the probability of being tspt-$k^\star$ or lower is at least $100 - \varepsilon$ % with a bound on $\varepsilon$.
"Higher number of threads is more dangerous." Under some assumptions regarding the algorithm, it could be formally proven (!) that in the same timespan, the probability of a thread-safety violation occuring is higher for bigger thread numbers.

To get fruitful answers, we should suppose additional constraints:

A tspt-$k$-algorithm should become slower with fewer threads. (Otherwise, serial execution on one thread with all others waiting would need to be considered.)
(another perspective of 1) Each thread should be relevant regarding the execution. (Otherwise, $k$ may be blown up for free without new knowledge.)
You are free in the choice of your models -- let it be π-calculus, pseudocode in a given textbook, a real-world Java program, ...

Please excuse the handspun notation, as a working programmer (only serial programs) I have unfortunately no overview regarding the research literature.

Maybe not what you're looking for, but that reminds me of this paper I once read. Their assumptions is that bugs are triggered by a small set of instructions that must happen in a certain order. They use that assumption to design a scheduler to generate interleavings to find such bugs with higher probability.
